# std::promise with custom allocator appears to use global new

Tags: c++11, promise, future, allocator

Context: I am writing a library that exposes custom allocators in many stdlib data structures for users who want to customize memory allocation for real-time performance.

I want to use a custom allocator with `std::promise` and `std::future`. My understanding is that when an allocator is passed to `std::promise`, its `future` object also uses that custom allocator.

My test overrides global new and delete to track the number of times the default operators are called. I also implement a custom allocator that uses `malloc` and `free` but uses different state to count the allocations/deallocations (this would be replaced with a real-time safe allocator in a real example).

It appears that when I call `std::promise::set_value` for a "large" object, global operator new and delete are called, even though the `promise` was constructed with a custom allocator.

Here is a basic example. (Allocator boilerplate removed for brevity, you can see the full, compilable version on Gist: https://gist.github.com/jacquelinekay/a4a1a282108a55d545a9)

```
struct Foo {
  std::vector<int, InstrumentedAllocator<int>> bar;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  (void) argc;
  (void) argv;
  InstrumentedAllocator<void> alloc;

  std::promise<Foo> promise_(std::allocator_arg, alloc);
  std::shared_future<Foo> future_ = promise_.get_future().share();

  // Start a thread that blocks for a few ms and sets the future value
  std::thread result_thread(
    [&promise_]() {
      Foo result;
      result.bar.push_back(1);
      result.bar.push_back(2);
      result.bar.push_back(3);
      // test_init starts counting calls to global new/delete
      // (stored in variables global_runtime_allocs/deallocs)
      test_init = true;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
      promise_.set_value(result);
      test_init = false;
    }
  );
  future_.wait();
  result_thread.join();
  std::cout << "Runtime global allocations: " << global_runtime_allocs << " (expected: 0)" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Runtime global deallocations: " << global_runtime_deallocs << " (expected: 0)" << std::endl;
}
```

The global operator new for this example also prints the size of the "runtime" allocation (from `std::promise::set_value`), resulting in this output:

```
$ clang++ promise_allocator.cpp -std=c++11 -lpthread
$ ./a.out
Allocation size: 16
Runtime global allocations: 1 (expected: 0)
Runtime global deallocations: 1 (expected: 0)
```

I get the same results on gcc 4.8 and Clang 3.4. Is this the correct interpretation of the standard? I would expect `set_value` to use the `promise`'s allocator.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069443/custom-allocators-vs-promises-and-packaged-tasks -- that one talks about unavoidable mutex allocations in visual studio.  Can you track how big your allocations are?

Comment: I added a print statement to global `operator new` to print the size argument. The allocation from `set_value` is 16 bytes.

Comment: How big is your "large" object?  Can you make it ridiculous, like 1000 bytes?  Ie, is this a problem similar to the `std::mutex` problem linked above, or is it something different...

Comment: I changed the program to push 1000 entries into the vector in the "Foo" struct and the allocation size was unchanged.

Comment: No, make a large array, not a vector.

Comment: ok, the struct now has a `std::array<int, 1000>` and the allocation size is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the 4.9 release series libstdc++ that is fixed in the version 5 release series. Running your gist on Wandbox with [version 5.1](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/o8M8m3newp6bIj2C) or higher produces only the output:

```
Runtime global allocations: 0 (expected: 0)
Runtime global deallocations: 0 (expected: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

With a combination of debugger backtracing and combing through GCC's stdlib implementation, I've figured out *why* this happens, though I don't have a solution or workaround for myself.

`std::promise::set_value` calls an internal function of its future, `future::_M_set_result`. [1] Passing the function object `__res` into this function calls the constructor of `_Function_base`, perhaps because the signature of the function does not pass `__res_` by reference. [2] The constructor of `_Function_base` calls `_M_init_functor`, which either does a placement new if the function is using local storage or allocates a new object. [3] For some reason that I still haven't determined, the function used internally by `future` does NOT use local storage and therefore allocates in the constructor.

From skimming the working draft of the standard that I could find [4], the standard not specific about the expected behavior of allocations in `promise`. However, it is inconvenient that I can't control the allocation behavior of the function used internally by `promise`, and I will probably file a bug in gcc about it.

1. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-4_8_4-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/future#L985
2. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-4_8_4-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/future#L352
3. https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-4_8_4-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/functional#L1957
4. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf